# Preencher lista de objetos com dados do SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tenho um objeto do tipo Estado ondo contem os seguintes atributos.

idEstado (String), siglaEstado (String)

E tenho uma tabela já preenchida no banco de dados com os mesmos atributos acima.
Porém gostaria de retornar todos esses dados para uma coleção desse objeto para que eu possar carregar um spinner. Porem o metodo que fiz de busca desses dados está retornando null.

Classe que cria o banco:

```
 public static final String NOME_BANCO = "carona";
private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;

public BancoDados(Context context) {
    super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_ESTADO);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CIDADE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_INSERE_UF);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


String SQL_ESTADO = "CREATE TABLE [Estado](\n" +
        "[EstadoId] [INT] NOT NULL,\n" +
        "[Sigla] [char](2) NOT NULL,\n" +
        "CONSTRAINT [PK_Estado] PRIMARY KEY ([EstadoId])\n" +
        ");";

String SQL_CIDADE = "CREATE TABLE [Cidade](\n" +
        "[CidadeId] [int] NOT NULL,\n" +
        "[Nome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,\n" +
        "[EstadoId] [INT] NULL,\n" +
        "CONSTRAINT [PK_Cidade] PRIMARY KEY ([CidadeId]\n" +
        "), CONSTRAINT[FK_ESTADO] FOREIGN KEY ([EstadoID]) REFERENCES [Estado] ([EstadoID])\n" +
        ");";


String SQL_INSERE_UF =  "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES " +
        "(11,'MG')," +
        "(19,'RJ')," +
        "(26,'SP');" ;
```

Classe com Método que busca no banco e cria lista de Estados

```
public class EstadoDAO {


public SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatbase;
public BancoDados bancoDados;

public EstadoDAO (Context context) { bancoDados = new BancoDados(context);}


public List<Estado> carregarEstado (){

    List<Estado> estadoList = new ArrayList<>();

    this.sqLiteDatbase = this.bancoDados.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatbase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Estado",null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
        Estado estado = new Estado();
        estadoList.add(estado);

            estado.setIdEstado(cursor.getString(0));
            estado.setSiglaEstado(cursor.getString(1));

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }
        return estadoList;

    }



}
```

1ª Duvida: Porque esta retornando null do banco?

2ª Duvida: Outra dúvida que tenho é que na verdade serão 2 spinner um para estado outro para cidade, como faço para que ao selecionar o Estado eu realize um select na tabela de cidade para carregar somente com as cidades do estado indicado.

Answer (score 2):

**1** - Você está adicionando o objeto **vazio** na  sua ArrayList. Tenta assim:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatbase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Estado",null);   
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
       Estado estado = new Estado();

       estado.setIdEstado(cursor.getString(0));
       estado.setSiglaEstado(cursor.getString(1));

       estadoList.add(estado);

    }while(cursor.moveToNext());

}
    return estadoList
```

Algumas sugestões:

- Criar uma classe para armazenar as strings com o SQL, assim facilita o reuso em outras classes.
- Uma classe com todas as queries que você vai precisar.
- Sugestão de código para ler os dados:

  ```
  DBAdapter meuBanco= new DBAdapter(this);
  meuBanco.openDB();
  Cursor cursor = meuBanco.getEstados();

  while(cursor.moveToNext()){
      String estadoId = cursor.getInt(0);
      String estadoSigla= cursor.getString(1);

      EstadoObj estado= new EstadoObj(estadoId, estadoSigla);
      estadoList.add(estado);
  }

  if(!(estado.size()<1)){
      // faça algo, se a lista não for vazia
  }
  meuBanco.closeDB();
  ```

  }

**2** -  Sobre o Spinner, implementa o ItemSelectedListener:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        //seu código
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // seu código
    }

});
```